# Issue with foreach loop (Combining Commands)

Tags: powershell, vcenter

The script below works out great for identifying licensing for each individual host across multiple vCenters. What I am trying to include is the tag for each host as well. When I run the command individually it works fine, however when I run it as part of the code it is not functioning correctly. I highlighted the section if anyone can please take a look thanks.  **The line of code with the issue is commented out within the script below.**

I attempted pushing this into a variable outside and insideof the foreach loop but I am receiving either 0 output, or the same output across each object.

Below is the actual command I put inside the foreach loop which is not functional.

```
(Get-VMhost | where{$_.Category -like "*Host*"})
```

```
$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
# Declare our list of vCenters
[array]$vclistall = "vcenter01"
# Ensure were not connected to any vcenters
if ($DefaultVIServer.Count -gt 0) {
    Disconnect-VIServer * -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -Force:$true > $null
}
[array]$report = $null
foreach ($ScriptVCInstance in $vclistall) {
    $connection = Connect-VIServer $ScriptVCInstance -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($connection) {
        Write-Host "Collecting License Assets on vCenter $($ScriptVCInstance)"
        # Get the license manager assets
        $LicenseManager = Get-view LicenseManager
        $LicenseAssignmentManager = Get-View $LicenseManager.LicenseAssignmentManager
        $licenses = $LicenseAssignmentManager.GetType().GetMethod("QueryAssignedLicenses").Invoke($LicenseAssignmentManager, @($null))
        #Format the asset into an object
        foreach ($license in $Licenses) {
            $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "vCenter" -Value $($connection.name)
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Entity" -Value $($license.EntityDisplayName)
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Display Name" -Value  $($license.Properties | where{$_.Key -eq 'ProductName'} | select -ExpandProperty Value)
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Product Version" -Calue $($License.Properties | where{$_.Key -eq 'FileVersion'} | select -ExpandProperty Value)
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "License" -Value $($license.AssignedLicense.LicenseKey)
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "License Name" -Value $($license.AssignedLicense.Name)
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Cost Unit" -Value $($license.Properties | where{$_.Key -eq 'CostUnit'} | select -ExpandProperty Value)
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Used License" -Value $($license.Properties | where{$_.Key -eq 'EntityCost'} | select -ExpandProperty Value)
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Total Licenses" -Value $($license.AssignedLicense.Total)

            # Issue-->  $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Tag" -Value $(Get-VMhost | where{$_.Category -like "*Host*"})

            $report += $object
            if ($DefaultVIServer.Count -gt 0) {
                Disconnect-VIServer * -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -Force:$true > $null
            }
        } #end foreach $license
    } else { # Else for if $connection
        Write-warning "Not connected to vCenter $($ScriptVCInstance)"
    } # endif $connection
} # End foreach $ScriptVCInstance
# write-out as a CSV file
Write-host "Exporting CSV $($env:USERPROFILE)\Licensed-Assets.csv"
$report | Sort-object "vCenter","License","Entity" | Export-csv "$($env:USERPROFILE)\Licensed-Assets.csv" -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
$sw.Stop()
$sw.Elapsed
```

Comment: `however when I run it as part of the code it is not functioning correctly` - in what way is it not functioning correctly?

Comment: Do you really want to add the whole (get-vm) object?  Usually you are piping to select -expand to add a string.  `| Select -expand category`?

Comment: @gms0ulman  I wrote below: I attempted pushing this into a variable outside and insideof the foreach loop but I am receiving either 0 output, or the same output across each object.